# running a simple server using python's SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, http, server

I am trying to create a local server by following the instructions [here](https://lifehacker.com/start-a-simple-web-server-from-any-directory-on-your-ma-496425450)

I ran the command and got this:

```
➜ ~ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

However I don't know how to access the files in the directory that I started the server in. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: type localhost:8000 in your browser

Comment: Thanks, that works, you can make that an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: great and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can type `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser.. the important bit being an address, `localhost` followed by the port `8000` in this case.